# multiple pie-charts with responsive not working in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to built multiple pie-charts with responsive. Based on the width the pie-charts position is not changing. I am using the below code and i have attached the screenshot. Please refer the screenshot.

```
<div id="container" style="height:600px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'pie',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Candidate percentage per party',
            align: 'center'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                size: '200'
            }
        },
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: '#3E576F',
                fontSize: '14px'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    html:"Whales unite",
                    style:{left:"180",top:"20"}
                },
                {
                    html:"Star Wars (Dark Side)",
                    style:{left:550,top:"20"}
                },
                {
                    html:"South African GOATS",
                    style:{left:151,top:290}
                }
            ],
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.key + ': ' + this.y + ' (' + Math.round(this.percentage) + '%)';
            }
        },
        series:[
            {
                data:[
                    {name:"Jabu Nkosi",y:24},
                    {name:"Ryan Ryan",y:24},
                    {name:"Ryan Bouwer",y:24},
                    {name:"Marco  Engels",y:24},
                    {name:"Adrian Nair",y:24},
                    {name:"Mateen Waja",y:24},
                    {name:"Zach Pillay",y:24}
                ],
                name:"Whales unite",
                center:[200,150],
                size:150
            },
            {
                data:[
                    {name:"Rui Gomes da silva",y:5}
                ],
                name:"Star Wars (Dark Side)",
                center:[200,400],
                size:150
            },
            {
                data:[
                    {name:"Keegan fan Numba 1 fan",y:7},
                    {name:"Laeekah fan Numba 1 fan",y:7}
                ],
                name:"South African GOATS",
                center:[600,150],
                size:150
            }
        ];
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: thanks for your response @jlbriggs. https://jsfiddle.net/boopathi008/8ed9974p/1/

Comment: I think that specifying specific positions for your elements is going to negate any form of responsiveness.  I didn't realize you had all three charts in one container. If you want truly responsive charts, I think you will need to build them in their own containers.

Comment: thanks for your response @jlbriggs can i do it single container only.

Comment: You need to set size and center as percentage strings, e.g. '15%' https://jsfiddle.net/8ed9974p/2/

Comment: ok thanks :) Its working fine. @jlbriggs

Comment: i have one more doubt. my first pie chart is empty, second is set of value is there. that time also alignment changed. https://jsfiddle.net/boopathi008/8ed9974p/